# Word select: 食べます？／飲みます？

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage, verbs, word-usage

食べ物の場合は動詞「食べる」を使いますが、飲み物の場合は動詞「飲む」を使います。ところが、食べ物と飲み物をいっしょに出た場合はどの動詞を使いますか。

> 例①：パンとミルクを...（食べます？／飲みます？）…
>   例②：コーヒーとりんごを...（食べます？／飲みます？）…

Comment: 英語ならどうなる？日本語は同じです。

Comment: 本当うですか？"sloppy"でもいい？

Comment: ^ sloppy なので、ちゃんとした文章を書くときにはあんまりよくないです。ところで「日本語は同じです」ってどういう意味ですか。

Comment: 英語で”apple”と"coffee”両方言ってどっちの動詞を使うって考えたら、にってる答えが出る。って言ったかった。

Comment: ^ apple には eat, coffee には drink, で日本語も同じですね。でも英語には have  があるので便利ですね。

Comment: 「パンをコーヒと一緒に食べました」は如何でしょうか？

Answer (score 9, accepted):

そういう場合は、両方の動詞を使い、「パンを食べ（て）、牛乳を飲む」、「リンゴを食べ（て）、コーヒーを飲む」と言い表すことができます。

しかし、よりお勧めしたいのは、「頂{いただ}く」という謙譲語・丁寧語をこの機会に覚えておくことです。「頂くを」使えば、食べ物と飲み物のどちらにも対応できるからです。

「パンと牛乳を頂く」、「リンゴとコーヒーを頂く」などと、動詞ひとつで表現できます。

Comment: `「頂く」` -- おお・・ reminds me of : https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/9821/9831